# Obtener ultimos digitos de una variable NUMBER en un ciclo PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

quería pedirles ayuda ya que no puedo conseguir obtener los últimos 3 digitos una variable en formato NUMBER, me dice que SUBSTRING es un identificador no válido, también intenté con RIGHT(sueldo_base,1) y me aparecía el mismo mensaje.

Cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo? muchas gracias

[image: Mi codigo]

Comment: Muestra el código _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: El código siempre debe ser en modo texto, con el formato para código para que los lectores puedan copiarlo y probarlo. Por eso nunca se debe anexar una imagen.

Comment: Este código no parece ser Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

NO existe en Oracle SQL ni PL/SQL una función de nombre "SUBSTRING".

La función para extraer una parte o sección de una cadena de caracteres es:

```
SUBSTR(texto, inicio, cantidad)
```